# Android Studio: Reaching assets files from any java class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, assets

I need to implement a chatbot application with using AIML. So I need to store my AIML files in my local storage of my device. And my library that name is program-ab (`https://code.google.com/archive/p/program-ab`) uses `File folder = new File(path);` method to get AIML files from device local storage.

First I created a assets folder like;

```
|--app
|----manifests
|----java
|----assets
|----res
```

and added my required AIML file to assets folder.

Than I need to reach my folders with;

```
   File file = new File(this.getBaseContext().getFilesDir(), "assets");
    if (file.exists())
    {
        System.out.println("OK");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("NO");
    }
```

but it returns me "NO" response. So what can I do to store and reach my AIML files from my application.

Answer (score 0):

Don't store your files on the /app folder in your projects. It's not a good practice.
Store the files on the local storage instead.

Answer (score 0):

To access files stored in your application's assets you should use [AssetManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager).

You can retrieve an instance by calling:

```
final AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
```

Once you have the AssetManager you can access all asset filenames by calling:

```
final String[] names = assets.list("");
```

You can specify a particular path to search within assets by passing the relative path instead of ""

Find the one you want and open it as an InputStream by calling:

```
final InputStream in = assets.open(name);
```

You can also close the AssetManager when you're done using it:

```
assets.close();
```

And as usual you should close your file streams once you're done.

AssetManager by design does not give you the actual File objects, I'd assume this is to preserve them as they should be read only.

To convert this into a File object you can use you'll need to copy the asset's contents to a file in your app's storage directory.

```
final File file = new File(context.getFilesDir(), name);
final OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
ByteStreams.copy(in, out);
in.close();
out.close();
```

ByteStreams is available in [Google Guava](https://github.com/google/guava), Apache Commons also has a similar method to copy from one stream to another inside IOUtils.

This is a heavy operation so it might be worth copying the assets to local storage when your app is first started and then using the local copies so you don't need to copy each time.

Unless of course you have a huge number of files in which case you might need to develop a process to copy and clear them as required while the app runs.

Comment: But my library uses `file` object to reach necessary files. Do I really have to use `InputStream `?

Comment: From what I can see AssetManager only exposes streams, I assume this is to protect the files from being edited.

In order to get access to File objects you'd need to copy the assets to your apps file directory on the device.

I've added a section about how to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your editing. But I didn't understand that if I have a specific direction to add my predefined AIML files in application folder structure.

Comment: When you add a file to assets in android studio it gets bundled up as part of the apk the same way that resources do. When you call getFilesDir it gives you a reference to your app's storage directory on the device's local storage. This is not the same as the folder structure in android studio, all the contents of those files were converted into the apk which you can only access by calling methods on context such as "assets".

Comment: So I need to add my files to on my local storage not assets direction in android studio such as facebook application. When I open my file manager folder in my mobile device I see specific folders of other applications.